# Qtspim console issue

Tags: assembly, console, mips, cpu-registers, qtspim

My qtspim was first showing the 'repeating of main label error but I loaded it again now I see the registers getting highlighted when I run my program but it doesn't show anything on console although I have activated it from the windows dropdown bar. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXzrw.png)

Comment: There won't be anything in the console unless you actually perform a system call that outputs to the console. And we have no idea if you're doing that since you haven't shown us any code.

Comment: Use "Reinitialize & Load File" and Initialize, not "Load File"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.